# How to send custom value to sweetalert javascript code from PHP?

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

I want to warn user on attempting to delete a file. how can I transfer some details via the `html button` to this javascript ? for example, each time the user will be deleting different files, so the button should sent different file id to the `fileid` part of the url.

here is the .js example

```
    <script>
document.getElementById("custom-sa-warning") && document.getElementById("custom-sa-warning").addEventListener("click", function() {
    Swal.fire({
        html: '<div class="mt-3"><lord-icon src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/gsqxdxog.json" trigger="loop" colors="primary:#f7b84b,secondary:#f06548" style="width:100px;height:100px"></lord-icon><div class="mt-4 pt-2 fs-15 mx-5"><h4>Are you Sure ?</h4><p class="text-muted mx-4 mb-0">Are you Sure You want to Delete this Account ?</p></div></div>',
        showCancelButton: !0,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-primary w-xs me-2 mb-1",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete It!",
        cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-danger w-xs mb-1",
        buttonsStyling: !1,
        showCloseButton: !0
    }).then((result) => {
   if (result.value) {
     window.location.href = `https://somedimain.com/delete.php?id=fileid`
   }
 });
})
</script>
```

Here is the html to initiate the popup

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="custom-sa-warning">Click me</button>
```

Already tried
`var test = 'https://somedimain.com/delete.php?id=$fileid';`

```
if (result.value) {
       var example = test;
     window.location.href = example
   }
```

, it works, but how can I change this `var test` value from a button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `data-fileId` attribute to your button and when you click to button, get clicked buttons 'data-fileId'. it should be like this

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="custom-sa-warning" data-fileId="write your fileId">Click me</button>
```

js:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("custom-sa-warning") && document.getElementById("custom-sa-warning").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var el = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var fileId = el.getAttribute('data-fileId');
    Swal.fire({
        html: '<div class="mt-3"><lord-icon src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/gsqxdxog.json" trigger="loop" colors="primary:#f7b84b,secondary:#f06548" style="width:100px;height:100px"></lord-icon><div class="mt-4 pt-2 fs-15 mx-5"><h4>Are you Sure ?</h4><p class="text-muted mx-4 mb-0">Are you Sure You want to Delete this Account ?</p></div></div>',
        showCancelButton: !0,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-primary w-xs me-2 mb-1",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete It!",
        cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-danger w-xs mb-1",
        buttonsStyling: !1,
        showCloseButton: !0
    }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
     window.location.href = "https://somedimain.com/delete.php?id=" + fileId
    }
  });
})
</script>
```